# Is preloading possible for classes from modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, preload

I'm using voting gem [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable). That's just for explanation, my **question is wider** than just a 'question about gem'. If you have any example for the same situation but another 'dressing' - there's no problem.

In two words I'd like to preload votes along with posts. But it's not so easy because Vote class comes from module. So I can acces it only by calling `ActsAsVotable::Vote`. And doing something like

`@posts = Post.where(user_id: user.id).includes(:vote)`

leads to an error:

`Association named 'vote' was not found on Post; perhaps you misspelled it?`

QUESTION: Is there any way to preload data from classes coming from external modules?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Post.where(user_id: user.id).includes(:votes)`?

Comment: Should, but the result is the same. It doesn't see Vote class.

Comment: You need to do .includes(:votes_for) (that's the actual name of the relation as defined in the gem)

Comment: @joost Awesome! You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably work:

```
@posts = Post.where(user_id: user.id).includes(:votes_for)
```

Source: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/599995f7ec5aa0f8a04312768fc956e9003d32d4/lib/acts_as_votable/votable.rb#L38